# Svelte app fails on mobile browsers due to optional chaining SyntaxError

Tags: typescript, svelte, vite, svelte-3

I'm working on a simple Svelte app, using Vite as a build tool, which works fine on my desktop browsers (Chrome/Edge alike), but when trying to browse the dev build (`pnpm dev --host`) on a mobile device (either an Android simulator or my iPhone) it doesn't work:

[image]

It looks like the ES support is different, or Vite doesn't transpile this code further to a compatible version for those browsers. The same `?.nickname` expression works fine in desktop.
I also tried changing target to ES2015 in `tsconfig.json` but the .svelte file in the browser doesn't change...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find support for `?.` or [Optional chaining here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

The support is widespread so unless you are testing legacy mobile phones it should work. I suspect there is something wrong with your emulator then.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I mixed up chrome inspector tabs from my emulator and tablet, and here's what was going on:
- the emulator has Chrome 74 --> `?:` not supported
- the tablet had another issue
In the end I just assumed the tablet (and iPhone) had the same issue with optional chaining but it's a different thing (with auth0) which I can fix. I'll close the issue.

Comment: Still, it bothers me that changing `tsconfig.target` to ES2015 doesn't make the `?.` operator go away in the processed App.svelte file...

Comment: Then it is likely a bug in Svelte toolchain and needs to be inspected why it does not build correctly and checked if it is generic issue or an issue just for you.